# Kafka producer metrics are not presented

Tags: spring, prometheus, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer

I'd like to add metrics to my application and count how many messages are sent and consumed to/from my kafka. So I tried to add **MicrometerConsumerListener** and **MicrometerProducerListener** to Consumer and producer factories.

My factories configurations are:

```
@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MyDto> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                props.getBootstrapAddress());
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                JsonSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean(name = "producerTestFactory")
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerTestFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                props.getBootstrapAddress());
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, MyDto> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, prop.getBootstrapAddress());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                new ErrorHandlingDeserializer(new StringDeserializer()));
    }
```

And producerFactories for messages with errors.
Then I created kafkaTemplates:

```
@Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, MyDto> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean(name = "testKafkaTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> testKafkaTemplate(
            @Qualifier("producerTestFactory") ProducerFactory<String, String> testKafkaProducer
    ) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(testKafkaProducer);
    }
```

After all, In my library I've created a bean post processor that added micrometer listeners:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaMonitoringPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof ConsumerFactory cf) {
            cf.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener(meterRegistry));
        } else if (bean instanceof ProducerFactory pf) {
            pf.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry));
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

The problem is that I see all consumer's metrics. And do not see the producer's one.
Also I've tried to add MicrometerProducerListener directly in my producerFactory(), and it works. But it should work from the library, because it should be scalable solution.

P.s. I've tried to debug it, and seen that beanPostProcessor worked correctly, listeners were added to factories

Comment: Is it applied to both factories? Are you using the producer from a `@PostConstruct` method (before the BPP runs)? You should **never** do that. Try making the BPP `static` so it is defined earlier in the context lifecycle. If you can't figure it out, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace.

Comment: @GaryRussell, thanks for the idea. There was incorrect order of beans definition. In my example bean testKafkaTemplate has metrics, but kafkaTemplate is not. I've added KafkaTemplate to BPP and add listener there